# Google Firebase Authentication example doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to write a simple test of the Firebase user creation. I just copied the code from the documentation and then changed the url, but it doesn't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String FIREBASE_URL = "https://<firebase-application-name>.firebaseio.com/";

    Firebase ref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    }

    public void signup(View view) {
        ref.createUser("bobtony@firebase.com", "correcthorsebatterystaple", new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {
                System.out.println("Successfully created user account with uid: " + result.get("uid"));
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                System.out.println("error");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what documentation are you using as reference?

Comment: You're using the documentation for the Firebase 2.x SDK. Your project is likely created on the new Firebase console (firebase.google.com) and can only use the new Firebase Authentication SDK. For documentation on that, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth

Answer (score 0):

> Before retrieving and saving data from the Firebase server, you need to set up authentication and add rules that restrict access to data and validate user input before it’s saved.

Kindly change the **RULES** of your Firebase project

```
{

 "rules": {

".read": "auth == null",

".write": "auth == null"

  }

}
```

Or try below code

```
  {

  "rules": {

      ".read": true,

      ".write": true

  }

}
```